# Two way binding is not setting title to Toolbar

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am not able to set title to toolbar using data-binding in Android. Here is my implementation:

Layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:theme="@style/Toolbar" />
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Code for setting toolbar:

```
private void setUpToolbar() {
        setSupportActionBar(activityCupBinding.toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar()!= null) {
            activityCupBinding.toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.addCup));
        }
    }
```

When I debug above code it tells me **activityCupBinding.toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.addCup))**
as undefined.

Here is style used for toolbar

```
<style name="Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/merriweather</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Does `findViewById` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your AppTheme inherits from

`parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Dark"`

OR

`parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"`